# Importing members from multiple classes in single function to build kotlin dsl

Tags: kotlin, extension-methods, gradle-kotlin-dsl

- I have a special use case to provide dsl to our library consumer.
- I want to expose single function and inside that function, I want all the required utilities are imported.
- Because of some restriction I can not aggregate all the utilities
  in single class file and have something like this

```
    fun script(block: Ctx.() -> Unit) {}
```

- Basically I want something like this

```
    fun script(block: Ctx1.() -> Ctx2.() -> Unit) {}
```

**Complete dummy example is here**

```
    class RandomNumeric {
        fun randomInt() = Random(10).nextInt()
        fun randomLong() = Random(10).nextLong()
    }

    class RandomString {
        fun randomString() = UUID.randomUUID()
    }

    fun randomGenerator(block: RandomNumeric.() -> RandomString.() -> Unit) {
        val randomNumeric = RandomNumeric()
        val randomString = RandomString()
        block(randomNumeric)(randomString)
    }

    fun main() {

        // this is how I have to use it currently
        randomGenerator {
            {
                randomInt()
                randomLong()
                randomString()
            }
        }

        /*******************************
        // this is how I would like to use it
        randomGenerator {
            randomInt()
            randomLong()
            randomString()
        }
        *******************************/
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use extension functions for that:

```
class MyDsl

fun MyDsl.randomInt() = Random(10).nextInt()
fun MyDsl.randomLong() = Random(10).nextLong()

fun MyDsl.randomString() = UUID.randomUUID()

fun randomGenerator(block: MyDsl.() -> Unit) {
    MyDsl().block()
}

fun main() {

    randomGenerator {
        randomInt()
        randomLong()
        randomString()
    }
}
```

Comment: I could do that, but as I said, I do not have control over those classes and every such class has 10-20 functions. So writing extensions for each one of them is not feasible.